# Whats the purpose of public url in Laravel?

Tags: url, laravel, public

When we setup laravel, the default url will have "public" on it.

Example : localhost/laravel/public/users

We know that we always wanted to remove the "public" in our url specially when we go to production.

I searched in the internet and looks like removing the "public" url needs some work to achieve like moving files to other folder, modifying .htaccess, etc...

My question is, whats the purpose of "public" url? 
Why doesnt laravel provide an easy way of removing the "public" url..
I know Laravel is popular these days but why give beginners a headache in just removing a part of the url?

Let me know your thoughts

Comment: "When we setup laravel, the default url will have 'public' on it." Not if you're doing it right, you won't. Your webserver should be pointed at `public` for the document root.

Answer (score 2):

The `public` directory holds all your files that should be **accessible from the outside**.
This way nobody can access any other file in your application.

How do you remove the `public` in your URL? Well you don't "remove" it at all. Instead you should point your domain (virtual host) *directly* at `public` (this is called Document Root)

If you don't have the possibility to do that (usually because your on a shared hosting with very restricted permissions) then and only then you need to move files or use a workaround with `.htaccess`. However if your hoster doesn't allow you to set the document root I would consider to switch to another one...

---

By the way: This is not really unique to Laravel. A lot of PHP frameworks do it (Zend Framework, Symfony, etc) all have a dedicated directory for files that should be accessible - separated from the framework core and your application.

---

If you're having trouble setting up your development environment correctly, you should try out [Laravel Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead). It's a pre-configured Vagrant box that makes it very easy to get your site locally up and running *(also comes without `public` in your URL!)*

Answer (score 1):

When you make your site's root point to the `public` folder, e.g. `www.mysite.com` points to `/path/to/laravel/public`, there are a few advantages.

Your files outside of `public`, like your .env with your passwords cannot be accessed doing things like `www.mysite.com/../.env` and other common "exploits" are prevented just by taking this simple approach.

It's quite a common pratice in other frameworks too, not only Laravel or PHP.